# Converting a string into a date when the month is in letters

Tags: sql-server

I have a column with strings like this: `AUG2016`

How to convert this in a date like that `08-01-2016`?

Comment: What happens when you convert?

Comment: I get this: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: What make/model/version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: I use SQL Server 2014

Comment: I do not have access to 2014, but in 2012 it just works. I would be astonished if MS eliminated a possibility to convert from that format in the next major release, but everything is possible in this universe. Other than rolling your own conversion using `substring()` and lookup tables I have no idea what to suggest. It baffles me that it does not work for you, sorry.

Comment: I suspect there is something else going on here. Like maybe you are doing this to a column and there is some other data in your column that is not valid. What is your actual query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Microsoft SQL Server 2012 you can just go ahead and convert:

```
select convert(datetime, 'aug2016') as dt

dt
-----------------------
2016-08-01 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I was over complicating, I was trying to convert month and year separately. Thank you

Comment: Ah, got it! Sounds like always trying to get SQL do everything for you first, before you roll your own processor, should the the way to go. Lazy one wins!

Answer (score 1):

You can write below query in MySql.

```
select date_format(str_to_date("AUG2016", '%b%Y'), '%m-01-%Y')
```

Here str_to_date("AUG2016", '%b%Y') will result into "2016-08-00". 
So we need to format the date, Thats why we need to use date_format() and specify required format into it.

Comment: Does `convert(datetime, 'AUG2016')` not work for you too? Oh, I see, you are actually talking of MySQL, while the OP works with MS SQL.